# stop the page of jumping php and html without using JavaScript

Tags: php, html

How I can stop the page from jumping to the top after submitting the form. I am not using any JavaScript in my web page. So I would prefer a solution without  JavaScript. This is my code:

```
<div > <?php $product_array = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC");
if (!empty($product_array)) { 
    foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){
?>
    <div class="product1">
        <form method="post"   action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
            <div ><a href="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["Description"]; ?>"><img  class="centerimage" src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["Picturepath"]; ?>"></a></div>      
         <div class="centerprice"><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?>(
         <?php echo $product_array[$key]["price"]."&#8364"; ?>)</div>
        <div class="quaadd"><input type="text" class="size1" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" /><input    class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Add to cart"  /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
        }
}
?>   
</div>
```

Comment: Your page is not "jumping to the top" - the browser loads the page when you submit the form - so the client actually view the new page for the first time. You can "scroll down" to the relevant element after submit, or read about ajax.

Comment: Your page isn't actually "jumping to the top" the page is being refreshed because you're submitting the form.

If you use AJAX to submit the form, this won't happen.

Comment: does this form post to itself, if so when you submit a form it will post the data to the page within the action. It will perform a full page request so loads the page in as new, so will go to the top.  SO if you want it to go to a section within that page then look at adding anchor tags to take you to the position you want after relaod

Answer (score 1):

Add ID attribute to the element you want to be scrolled to and then include it in your link.

Example: you want to see div class="quaadd" on top so you need to add id attribute to it (id="ShowMe"):

```
<div class="quaadd" id="ShowMe">
    <input type="text" class="size1" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" />
    <input    class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Add to cart"  />
</div>
```

And then modify your action on form (I guess that you are subbmiting this form on index.php)
    action="index.php?action=add&code=your_code#**ShowMe**

Edit (if you want the page to "jump" to the element you added to cart):

```
<div > <?php $product_array = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC");
if (!empty($product_array)) { 
    $i=1;
    foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){
?>
    <div class="product1" id="product_<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <form method="post"   action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>#product_<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <div ><a href="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["Description"]; ?>"><img  class="centerimage" src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["Picturepath"]; ?>"></a></div>      
         <div class="centerprice"><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?>(
         <?php echo $product_array[$key]["price"]."&#8364"; ?>)</div>
        <div class="quaadd"><input type="text" class="size1" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" /><input    class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Add to cart"  /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
$i++;
        }
}
?>   
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that but it take me to fixed place in the second raw of the products not where I clicked.
I have products could reach to thousands see the site www.merebuy.com

Comment: You need to set ID to a desired element, I guess you want the page to "jump" to the product you added to cart? Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Jan... Problem Solved
Your Code Is Working

Answer (score 0):

ok try to explain mine

add the following to the end of you action url:

```
   <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>#ADD-YOUR-ID-HERE">
    ...
   </form>
```

Then at the area, you would like the page to go to after being submitted, add the anchor id as follows:

```
   <a id="ADD-YOUR-ID-HERE" name="ADD-YOUR-ID-HERE"></a>
```

Then once submitted the page will jump directly to that anchor.

If you then want smooth scrolling then, you will need to use js to hijack the hashtag and do the scrolling.

PS on  side note you could add the url query into the form rather than the url itself.

```
  ?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]

  <input type="hidden" name="code" value"<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
```

reducing your action url to

```
  <form method="post" action="index.php#ADD-YOUR-ID-HERE">
```